# How to get a field value from next/prev asset

Tags: assets

`asset.getNext().fieldName` does not work but might help explain what I was aiming for.

To be more specific, for where there are multiple images in an entry, I want to assign a class to each depending on its next image’s field value. Also, the field I’m trying to get a value from is a radio field.

Comment: Not really - can you please post more detail?

Comment: Can you post your full template code? Sounds like `asset.getNext().fieldName` should work, but hard to tell without seeing more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this to work for what I needed:

```
{% set nextImage = image.getNext() %}
{% if nextImage %}

    {% if nextImage.checkboxFieldHandle.contains('value') %}
        {# Do something #}
    {% endif %}

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I never used that [`getNext()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/assetfilemodel#getNext) method with `craft.asset`, but maybe it works if you explicitly feed it with parameters?

Another idea is to use loop variables:

```
{% set myClass = not loop.last and entry.myAssets[loop.index].fieldName == '1' ? ' YEY' %}
```